# Android Studio Dead References After Moving Folders

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-studio, android-manifest

*See update below*

I recently changed my android project in android studio from one folder to another in Dropbox. Now all of my references to my res folders are dead, despite the file being intact. I tried cleaning, rebuilding, and invalidating. Still - these issues persist. Have a look, will you?

All red-marked areas come with this code...

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@string/app_name'
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.
```

And here is a screenshot of the marked areas:

[image]

Despite that I have a perfectly intact res folder and strings.xml file.

What could be going so wrong? All I did was move my files! I moved the whole folder, nothing more! 
Should I go back to eclipse? All was working so well before. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this is a duplicate, I am sorry - I tried several solutions to similar problems as mentioned before but to no avail.

Thank you and if you need more information please advise.

By the way here is the package explorer:
[image]

As you can see the manifest and res sources are all there.

**UPDATE**

The problem was found to be with the *build.gradle* file under *app*. With a simple addition of a line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
```

the gradle was reloaded by Android Studio and the project fixed, all proper references recognized. Thank you to the answerer!

Comment: Can you share the current screen shot of your solution explorer in Android Studio? You can add the image in your question above by editing.

Comment: Sorry, is that the list that pops up when I hover the top right that displays my problems? Or the projects? Here I'll post a few pics anyway. Just let me know if you need more.

Comment: Actually I need the left portion of your android studio (The package explorer). https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=solution+explorer+android+studio&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=657&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=gXUQVdKPEdajugSf2oD4DQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=F_M-_ZARCzKzLM%253A%3B7iVh3qSrIc0LnM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fi-msdn.sec.s-msft.com%252Fdynimg%252FIC661429.png%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fmsdn.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Flibrary%252Fwindows%252Fapps%252Fdn275875.aspx%3B624%3B337

Comment: I think that does it!

Comment: Yes, you have done it. And happy to say I have the solution. I am adding an answer in this thread. Hold on for few seconds.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for your quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following dependency in your build.gradle (Module App)

```
dependencies{
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

It should solve your problem.

In order to ignore gradle error while importing Android Studio Projects, follow the following steps:

Suppose you want to import a project Named: **MyProject1**

Copy the Project from its directory and paste in an **empty folder** (MUST BE EMPTY).

Make sure you have closed the MyProject1 from Android Studio by clicking Files>>Close Project

Click on the *Open an Existing Android Studio Project*

Locate the new directory, where you have pasted the MyProject1 folder.

**Recheck if "MyProject1" folder itself contains the "MyProject1" folder then it will not work.**

Now select the **MyProject1** folder and go ahead.

It will start the gradle build.

After successfull build the you can start refactoring.

**NOTE** :You have to copy the folder that contains the following files only:
[image]

For my case I am importing **Bdjobs** Projects.

Comment: Hey there! I am a little confused, because when I open the folder called: "AndroidStudioProjects" there are several options. I am wondering which ones represent my app: There are folders and files like settings gradle and localproperties. Do I need to go deeper into my more specific app? Do I take just the src files?

Comment: I think your project name is 'notificationalarm', right? So in your 'AndroidStudioProjects' folder, find the 'notificationalarm' folder. And check if there is another notificationalarm folder is inside of the parent folder then copy the folder which is inside.

Comment: Inside the "app" folder, since I think the name was just saved as "app", is see src, build, libs, and idea. It doesn't look like there is another app folder inside - just AndroidStudioProjects/app. I copied "app" into another separate folder but when I opened it it said there was nothing to show, is there something I need to do?

Comment: If its possible then, can you share the image of the AndroidStudioProjects folder? We are almost there man!

Comment: So close I know! Thanks for your help. I'll post a few shots.

Comment: Ok so, looking at your screenshot above, the AndroidStudioProjects folder is the one with all that I think

Comment: Exactly!! I have reviewed your shots. Actually 'AndroidStudioProjects' itself is your project. Copy this "AndroidStudioProjects" folder and consider it as "MyProject1" and follow the steps.

Comment: Do I have to delete the old project when I move it? My project is in Folder1 but if I move it to separate Folder2 do I need to delete it from Folder1, or delete it all together the whole folder?

Comment: Nope not necessary to delete. Because Android Studio allows it.

Comment: Okay, so I have two folders now - one is Workspace, which has the "old" AndroidStudioProjects deep inside it. And a new folder right next to it, just AndroidStudioProjects. I didn't change the name. Just the folder. I loaded by pressing "Import Existing", and it popped up just like the original, same tabs open and everything, with the same errors, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does the new AndroidStudioProject contains these 3 folder, app,build,gradle and few files? or it contains another AndroidStudioProjects?

Comment: Yes it has those. And a file called AndroidStudioProjects.iml, but thats fine, its not a folder.

Comment: I even changed the name a little - still came up as a new project with the same errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73618/discussion-between-mohammad-arman-and-william-brun).